# How to upload correctly an image with laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, storage

I have a problem, I am using Laravel 8 and I am creating a function that allows uploading images but when I call them through a label in my view it gives me a 404 error, I used php artisan storage:link to generate the link but it still does not allow me show the images, also check that the images are saved correctly in my storage/public folder and the images are located there

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user(); 

    $request->validate([
        'image_path' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
        'titulo' => 'required|string',
        'description' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $imagePath = $request->file('image_path')->store('public');

    PublicationModel::create([
        'image_path' => $imagePath,
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
    ]);

    return back()->with('success', 'Success.');
}
```

and this is my label:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($publication->image_path) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Publication">
```

Comment: use asset when viewing the image

Answer (score 0):

Correct Path in Storage: Verify that the storage/app/public directory contains the images in the correct location. It's excellent that you highlighted that the photographs are there.

Symbolic Link:
Make sure that the symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public has been created. You can generate the symbolic link using the following Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command creates a symbolic link in the public directory that points to the storage directory.

Path in Storage::url:
Double-check the Storage::url path. You are currently using `{{ Storage::url($publication->image_path) }}`. Make sure that $publication->image_path contains the correct relative path to the image within the storage/app/public directory.

If the images are stored directly in the public disk, you might need to adjust the path. If you are storing images in a subdirectory (e.g., public/images), the path should include that subdirectory.

Example:

```
{{ Storage::url('images/' . $publication->image_path) }}
```

Check URL in Browser:
Inspect the HTML output in your browser and check the URL generated for the image. Ensure that the URL is correct and points to a valid image file.

File Permissions:
Ensure that the storage directories and files have the correct permissions. The web server should have the necessary permissions to read from the storage directory.